# Get number with decimal value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to get the number with the decimal values.

Here is the following example:

I have two numbers: `621` which should be divided by `7` and result should be shown in the form of number with at least 3 digits decimal values. Accordingly the result should be `88.714`.

My Try1:

```
SELECT CAST(621/7 as DECIMAL(5,3));
```

Getting result is `88.000`.

Try 2:

```
SELECT CONVERT(DECIMAL(5,3), 621/7);
```

Getting result is `88.000`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to convert before you divide in order to avoid integer division.  Easiest way is:

```
cast(621*1.0/7 as Decimal(5,3))
```

In your examples, the division is happening first, then the convert/cast is being applied to that result.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT CONVERT(DECIMAL(18,0), 621)/7;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CAST(621.000/7 AS DECIMAL(5,3))
```

should work better as the division is completed before the cast in your example.

Comment: This will not work.  Parentheses are in the wrong place for cast, and I believe even after those are fixed it'll give a data truncation error.

Comment: he is right, edited to correct... i'm sleepy

Answer (score 0):

Sql Simply Treat **621** an **7** as int and it will give out put in int that You convert into Decimal. You have to Explicitly Define it as Decimal

```
declare @a decimal(10,3)=621
SELECT CAST(@a/7 as DECIMAL(5,3));
```

Here What you are trying to do

```
select 5/2
```

It will Always Give **2** whether you convert it into Decimal

```
select cast (5/2 as decimal(5,3))
```